# how to abbreviate the values of hexadecimal by using C++.

Tags: c++

How to abbreviated the values of hexadecimal by using C++. Means that if there is zero at the start of any value it can be ignored like if the value is 0012 it can be written as 12.

Comment: This is vague. Are you talking about literals ? Strings ? Something else ?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: i am writing a code which is convert the value hexadecimal into binary .. after that when user enters a value 0012 in hexadecimal, then 00 will b ignored and other characters will be written as 12.. can you help me? the code in a c++ format.

Comment: when you enter value as 0012 it will automatically be stored as 12 in int type variable, why can't you convert the integer to binary?

Comment: but when we "cout" that value it shows 0012 .. actually my data type is not in integer , its in char ..

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::hex` to read in the integer, it will take care of the leading zeroes.

```
unsigned int i;
std::cin >> std::hex >> i;
```

Input/Output:

```
> 00001234
i = 4660
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b5f8596c8daabeb)